# Checking dates of loan against previous multiple loan date entries

Tags: python, excel, loops, recursion, logic

I have to check whether a loan given out will be considered a valid loan or not.
The last column `is the loan valid` is what the result should be.

[image]

Criteria for loan:

- There should be no outstanding loan when the current one is being given

Problem is that I am trying to do this after the fact. I have to check every entry against all the previous entry to detemine if that loan is valid and one of the previous ones hasn't come due. 
Is there an efficient way to do this?
I can use Python or excel for the solution.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to show the Python code you're having trouble with

Comment: Edited to specify that I can use either Python or excel. I haven't been able to come up with a workable logic for it yet.